# loading on specific div in loop vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

This is my first question in this forum. I had been using jquery for a while but now I recently shifted to vuejs and found it's awesome.

Here is a little hitch I am having. The problem is I have to set `v-loading` on buttons in a loop and when I click I need it to be true (i.e starts showing). This is how I have done it but I don't know how to trigger it.

```
<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:0;" v-for="follow_request in follow_requests" v-loading.body="true">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <img class="img-circle" :src="follow_request.user.image | appendBaseUrl"
         style="height:60px;"/>
  </div>
</div>


v-loading.body="true"
```

I need to make it true and false on click, but only this specific `div`.

Comment: Is `follow_requests` an array of objects?

Comment: yes it is an array of object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typically suggest adding a property to the object that you are iterating over that represents the state. For each of the `follow_request` objects in your `follow_requests` array, add the property, `loading`.

Then you can use it in your template.

```
<div class="col-sm-12" 
     style="padding:0;" 
     v-for="follow_request in follow_requests" 
     v-loading.body="follow_request.loading"
     @click="follow_request.loading = !follow_request.loading>
```

Comment: nope it doesnt work. why would it work. follow_request doesnt have the field loading in it.. :/

Comment: @SyedAbdurRehmanKazmi Yes, I suggest *adding* it in the first line of the answer.

Comment: @SyedAbdurRehmanKazmi And if you don't have control of the data you receive from the server, you could still add it client side.

Comment: no i have access to server side and i added the field and now it works. thanks